# undo a .css(property, value) call?

Tags: jquery

How can I undo a `.css('display', 'block')` call so that it falls back to class-based behavior? I think I'm looking for something like `.css('display', null)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify an empty string, so that the inline property gets removed:

```
.css('display', '');
```

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, it is generally best to add a class to an element that has the desired style and then remove the class when you want to revert. Use the [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) methods. e.g.,

```
.blk{
    display: block;
 }
```

And then,

```
element.addClass('blk');
```

to set `display` to `block` and

```
element.removeClass('blk');
```

to revert. This may seem like an overkill for such simple a style, but can really help you if the style(s) are more complicated.

Comment: I'd do that for a complicated style, but I just want to make it visible, grab its size and hide it again.

Comment: While there are definitely advantages to setting a class (and I prefer that way myself in most cases), using the .css method inserts the css inline which would override all existing styles in the cascade. This is particularly useful when you don't have control of the css, such as a in a publicly available plugin

Answer (score -1):

Set the value to inherit like this: `.css('display', 'inherit')`. This way it uses the value defined in your class.

More info: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritvalue

Comment: This locks it to the parents style.

Comment: Isn't this what you were meaning by 'so that it falls back to class-based behavior'?

Comment: I want it to have the style that its own class attribute specifies, not the style that the parent has.